# system.io.file.exists not working in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-upload

I am removing the image from kendo upload control.

This is my code

```
  public ActionResult Remove(string[] fileNames)
    {

        if (fileNames != null)
        {
            foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
                var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(("~/AssetAttachments"),fileName));

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
                {
                     System.IO.File.Delete(physicalPath);
                }
            }
        }
        return Content("");
    }
```

Physicalpath i have is E:\karthik related\JPL\Dev\Src\AssetTrackingSystem\AssetTrackingSystem\AssetAttachments\Attach3.jpg

Even though file and directory available

```
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
```

is returning false and coming out of condition.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `physicalPath`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
{
     var physicalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AssetAttachments"), fullName);

     if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete(physicalPath);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(("~/AssetAttachments"),fileName));
 if (fi.Exists)
 {
   fi.Delete();
 }
```

Comment: even though f1.Exists returning False.

Comment: this is not coming jaimin

Comment: @Karthik u have multiple file to remove?